# WebDriver Drag n Drop Selected text from Google Search

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What I want is When I type "username" in Email Box and with the help of actions  i am selecting the text by double clicking it and I want to drag the "username" from email box to Firstname Box .

Can somebody Help me

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **Actions** Keyword for Drag and Drop Feature. **Below is the example for it**

```
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of Email Box");
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of FirstName Box"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(From)
.moveToElement(To)
.release(To)
.build();
.dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: Can you Provide Screenshot/html as how the flow should be?

Comment: this is my code 
  WebElement firstname = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));

  WebElement pass =driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
  Action dragAndDrop = builder.doubleClick(ele).clickAndHold()
  .moveToElement(pass)
  .dragAndDrop(ele, pass)
  .release(pass)
  .build();
  
  dragAndDrop.perform();

Comment: // Create object of actions class
Actions act=new Actions(driver);                                                              
** Search your firstname First then use below code**                                       
// find element which we need to drag
WebElement drag=driver.findElement(By.name("place searched xpath here"));
 
// find element which we need to drop
WebElement drop=driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")"));
 
// this will drag element to destination
act.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to send the same input to both the fields, why not use the same String variable

```
String username = "firstname";
```

to `.sendKeys(username);`

to both the Webelements `userName` and `firstName`. That way you `DragAndDrop` won't come into scene and will guarantee proper results every time.

:: Took the liberty to name your variables. ::